# Get name from Checkbox Group onchange event in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-events, lightning-checkbox-group

I currently have a checkbox group in a lightning web component and I have an onchange function setup to handle a selection. I have been reading the documentation, but can't find any information to extract information other than the value. I want to get the APIName which is stored in the name of the lightning-checkbox-group.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-checkbox-group/example

Below I have attached the code snippets from my html and js files for what I have tried to do.

```
<lightning-checkbox-group key={q.APIName}
       name={q.APIName}
       label={q.fieldLabel}
       options={q.options}
       value={q.value}
       onchange={handleChange}
>
```

```
    handleChange(e) {
        console.log(e.detail.name);
        console.log(e.detail.value);
        console.log(e.target.name);
        console.log(e.target.value);
        console.log(e.target);
        console.log(e.target.options);
        this.value = e.detail.value;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use currentTarget in place of target. You want the name of the lightning-checkbox-group component. target refers to the checkbox you clicked where as currentTarget will give you access to the component on which current-event listener was attached, that is, the checkbox group in this case.

Not only name you can access all other components attributes with currentTarget.

```
 handleChange(e) {
        console.log(e.currentTarget.name);
  }
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I'm new to JS and LWC so this was a big help!